# sort joined and grouped records in asscending order

Tags: java, sql

I have records from two tables that share the same id 'Input_ID'. these records are grouped by the Input_ID from one of the tables. the working query is written below:

```
 private void ProducedItems(){
  try{
    String sql ="select f.Input_ID as 'Production No.',f.Product,f.Standard_Weight as 'Benchmark(1KG)',sum(i.Quantity_Transfered_Weight) as 'Qnty Used',f.All_Item_Weight as 'Qnty Obtained',f.Price as 'Unit Price',f.Product_Value,f.Date"
            + " from final_production f INNER JOIN final_production_items i ON f.Input_ID=i.Input_ID GROUP BY f.Input_ID";  
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    productionTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    finally{
    try{
    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      }
    }
    }
```

please how do I make the above query get displayed in ascending order by f.Input_ID

Comment: have you tried to modify the query? What have you tried, where did you fail? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Is "Order by" added to the query not working? Where you have the problem?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: the "order by f.Input_ID ASC" doesn't work. I added that statement after the "GROUP BY f.Input_ID". records get displayed alright but ascending is executed

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
sql += "ORDER BY f.Input_ID"
```

should do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't know how large the result would be, it would be advised to add [Order By](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) to the end of the query:

```
... GROUP BY f.Input_ID ORDER BY f.Input_ID ASC;
```

In such cases it is advised to delegate the ordering to the database. As it will return an ordered set, and will allow you to iterate over it.

Comment: its not working bro. the records get displayed alright but it doesn't ascend by `f.Input_ID'

Comment: So the result display in ASC order, but the query returns incorrect order? Please explain. Did you tried executing this query in dbs command line? Were the results ordered as expected?

Comment: no @Beri , but I figured it out. there was a problem with the Input_ID column but had it fixed. thanks so much